# Accessing a matrix defined by paste (character string)

Tags: r

I've created a series matrices by pasting a county value based on my for loop to the word matrix.  This worked:

```
assign(paste("matrix",sort(unique(data$county), decreasing=FALSE)[k],sep=""), matrix(0,100,100))
```

I now want to write to different cells in this matrix but cannot.  This fails:

```
assign(paste("matrix",sort(unique(data$county), decreasing=FALSE)[k],sep="")[j,i],1)
```

The error is in the paste() since it has an "incorrect number of dimensions" since paste produces a vector and [j,i] is trying to access it as a matrix.  I've tried to wrap my paste in get(), eval(), etc. but just get different errors.

So the question is how do I make this character string return as a matrix that I can access with [j,i]?

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding the `assign` function and instead assigning your matricies into a named list.  That way the access is obvious and much more "R-ish".  However, the function you need is `get` rather than `assign` in your second statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code scheme instead:

Save a list of counties, sorted as you want (`decreasing=FALSE` is default):

```
counties <- sort(unique(as.character(data$county)))
```

Create zeroed matrices per county:

```
matrices <- sapply(counties, function(.)matrix(0,100,100), simplify=FALSE)
```

Write to specific cells:

```
matrices[[counties[k]]][j,i] <- 1
```

Note: I've added `as.character()` only to avoid problems with factors.

Comment: The list idea worked very well and made my code a lot cleaner.  I found this method to be the simplest to create and understand.  I'm not sure how it would work if I needed to change within my loop the dimensions of my matrix.  Does a list allow for multiple matrices of different dimensions within it?  (Thank you Justin, Richie, and Ferdindand)

Comment: @gren yes, each element of a list can be an arbitrary object, with its own dimension/attributes/types.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of what Justin meant in his comment, try this.

```
counties <- c("Nottinghamshire", "Derbyshire", "Leicestershire")
data_by_county <- replicate(
  length(counties), 
  matrix(0, 3, 4), 
  simplify = FALSE
)
names(data_by_county) <- counties
data_by_county
## $Nottinghamshire
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    0    0    0    0
## [2,]    0    0    0    0
## [3,]    0    0    0    0
## 
## $Derbyshire
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    0    0    0    0
## [2,]    0    0    0    0
## [3,]    0    0    0    0
## 
## $Leicestershire
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    0    0    0    0
## [2,]    0    0    0    0
## [3,]    0    0    0    0
```